# Trying to load mp3 file with nuxt, but getting 'You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.'

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've tried to add this to my nuxt.config file:

```
build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.mp3$/,
        include: '~/assets/sounds',
        loader: 'file-loader',
      });
    }
  }
```

but no use, it always gives me the error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:3)                                                                                                                    friendly-errors 13:48:16
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try to remove that `include: '~/assets/sounds',`